# How does the code on StackOverflow's 404 page work? (Pic included)

Tags: http-status-code-404

Everybody's seen this before, but what is this code?  I don't even know what language to tag this with.  Could somebody decipher it?

[image]

> Note- I would post this on meta but it *is* a programming question, just pretend I had said "I found this mystery code *somewhere*..."

Comment: I think its mostly in C given the `#define`s everywhere; however C has no `print` function as far as I know, and `main(){` is not giving a return type. Line 3 can be ignored as it is contained in comments `/*``*/`. I would think line 4 is CGI of sorts given the `404` output. Other than that I have know clue what-so-ever.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28625/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code

Comment: Thanks for the meta link:
"It is valid in C, Python, Perl, Ruby, Befunge-93, and Brainf*ck"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the lines except line four are commented with `#`. Line four simply prints `404`.

And here I thought it was some crazy `#define` macro.

Original posting is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites

Also seen here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28625/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured it out:

1: Compiler macro for v -> putchar

2: Compiler macro to replace print(x) with:

-

```
main(){
    putchar( 4 + putchar(putchar(52) - 4);
    return 0;
}
/* comment garbage from line 3 */
```

4: calls `print(202*2)`, but the `202*2` is thrown away by the macro;  simply inserts main here

5: redefines `exit()` to be nothing.

The final program post-pre-processing is just everything defined on line 2.

putchar returns the value it printed, so it first prints ascii 52, which is "4", then it prints a "0", returning the character for 0, which is then added to 4 and finally printed from the outermost printchar.

Obviously the final output is 404 but I was disappointed at how much of the code is just commented garbage and not actual interesting language quirks.  The only really interesting thing I suppose is that `putchar` returns the value of the character it prints, but even then...

### Edit

I'm really mad at myself for not thinking of it as if it were python, perl, ruby, or php :\

Comment: Actually, an extremely interesting question.  Thank you for posting.  It's a multi-language "polyglot" (to be duplicate redundant).  The author is Mark Rushakoff.  His explanation is here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28625/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code